# Basic four quadrant plot in DimpleJS (D3)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I'm trying out [DimpleJS](http://dimplejs.org/) for the first time and attempting to draw something like this:

[image]

Anybody know where I went wrong though? Nothing seems to appear.

http://jsbin.com/xosehedejo/1/edit

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var data = [
    {
      x:-1, 
      y:3
    }, {
      x:2, 
      y:-1.5
    }, {
      x:5, 
      y:2.5
    }
  ];
  
      var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
      var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
  
      dimple.filterData(data);
      myChart.addMeasureAxis("x");
      myChart.addMeasureAxis("y");
      myChart.draw();

};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chartContainer"></div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/mbostock/d3/master/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.2.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `filterData` in a way which makes the library crash, that's why nothing happens. Then when you correct that the axes will be drawn but nothing will be plotted, you need to add `series` to tell `dimple` how to plot your data.

If everything is done correctly then you should get something like [this](http://jsbin.com/parucocali/1/edit?html,js,output).

I have no prior experience with dimple, however to create this I used [this example](http://dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=bubbles_standard) and then [this wiki](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki) to understand how the different methods work together.

Comment: Trying to simplify it a little by removing type and legend. I see some people use `addSeries(null, ...)` but how come that doesn't work here? http://jsbin.com/yazutovezi/1/edit?js,output

Comment: Also, after removing type, when hovering each bubble there seems to be two instances of `x`: http://jsbin.com/yabokuqawe/1/edit?js,output

Comment: You must disaggregate the data by some variable, otherwise the bubbles will be stacked together.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken http://jsbin.com/yabokuqawe/1/edit?js,output should disaggregate, right?

Comment: It will disaggregate entires which doesn't share the same value for `x`. Those which do share the same value for `x` will be stacked together. You need something more like an unique identifier if you want all entries to be plotted separately.

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't able to get rid of the two instance thing though, so I made an issue over at the Dimple repo: https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/issues/157